# QGIS : How to calculate centroid on polygons with holes

Tags: qgis, postgis, polygon, centroids

I try to compute the centroid of polygons with holes on qgis. I did not manage to do it directly, I had to make a conversion to convex hulls before extraction.

I crashed my pgsql server trying to extract theses using ST_Centroid()

Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Are you looking for a PostGIS solution or can it be done using QGIS?

Comment: For PostGIS solution see here: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/724/how-can-i-find-a-point-inside-a-polygon-in-postgis. For general math see: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/623849

Comment: There may be invalid geometries in your data. PostGIS should handle polygons with holes just fine `SELECT ST_AsText(
ST_Centroid(
ST_GeomFromText(
'POLYGON (( 523 228, 523 238, 535 238, 535 228, 523 228 ), ( 527 231, 531 231, 531 235, 527 235, 527 231 ))')
))`

Comment: In Qgis (that you tagged as well) the Extension "Real Centroids" does what you want i think. It moves the centroid when it lies outside the polygon itself, what would be the case when it is in a hole. The calculations going on in the background are probably the same as in postgis, as this is mentioned in the extension.

Comment: What version of PostGIS? Can you post an example of the geometry that crashed the server?

Comment: Ty all, "Real centroids" are relevant in my case, I crashed my server on too many polygons centroid calculation or bad geometries, I must run some checks first.
Versions info (have to update to 2.2)
"POSTGIS="1.5.3" GEOS="3.3.1-CAPI-1.7.1" PROJ="Rel. 4.6.1, 21 August 2008" LIBXML="2.7.8" USE_STATS"